# NASM call label doesn't get called

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, ld

I'm doing some assembly coding using NASM on Linux but I've run into a problem.

```
global _start

section .text

testFunctionName:
    mov rdi, 12
    ret

_start:

    call testFunctionName

    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, 0
    int 0x80
```

then assembled and linked:

```
nasm -felf64 -F dwarf -g program.asm -o program.o
ld program.o -o program
```

testFunctionName is never jumped to. I verified this using GDB.
I haven't found relatable explanations elsewhere.
If somebody could explain what's happening and how to fix this,
I would appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you used the debugger incorrectly. Did you `step` into the function?

Comment: You should really be using the syscall interface with 64-bit Linux code rather than `int 0x80`

Comment: If you change the code to `testFunctionName: jmp testFunctionName`, does it go into an infinite loop?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer 1. The stack state is not unknown; it will contain a return address. 2. What `ret`? An infinite loop never returns.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Did you miss the part where I said `testFunctionName:`, not `_start:`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably using `nexti` or `next` which steps *over* calls, not into them.

**Set a breakpoint on the `mov rdi, 12` inside your function, or single-step *into* calls using `stepi` (or `si` for short).**

Or if you don't trust GDB, write a program whose exit status depends on whether the function runs or not.

```
testFunctionName:
    mov  ebx, 12
    ret

_start:
    xor   ebx, ebx   ; ebx=0

    call testFunctionName

    mov   eax, 1
    int   0x80       ; sys_exit(ebx), 32-bit ABI
```

Run this and `echo $?` to see that the exit status is 12, not 0, because the function *does* run unless your CPU is broken, or NASM or your linker are broken.

---

You could also put an illegal instruction inside your test function, like `ud2`.  Or a software breakpoint: `int3`.  Or a divide by zero.  Something that will raise an exception instead of letting your process make its exit system call.  Then you'll definitely notice whether it's called or not.

---

See also [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)  To make a native 64-bit exit(0) system call the same way glibc's `_exit()` function does, do

```
    xor   edi, edi     ; rdi=0
    mov   eax, 231     ; __NR_exit_group   from <asm/unistd_64.h>
    syscall            ; sys_exit_group(edi)
```